# Copycopter server crashing on Heroku (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, copycopter

I just started to try out copycopter but the out of the box app seems to be crashing.  I pretty much just ran the instructions at https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-server, but clearly something isn't working right.  This is the last several lines of my heroku log, but I can give more detail if needed.  I see that it's using old style plugins - is that related and if so what needs to be changed?

```
2013-07-12T03:05:16.164555+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-12T03:05:19.529261+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec thin start -p 35563`
2013-07-12T03:05:20.460981+00:00 app[web.1]: The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
2013-07-12T03:05:20.460981+00:00 app[web.1]: Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
2013-07-12T03:05:21.439397+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:2)
2013-07-12T03:05:21.439132+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: You have Rails 2.3-style plugins in vendor/plugins! Support for these plugins will be removed in Rails 4.0. Move them out and bundle them in your Gemfile, or fold them in to your app as lib/myplugin/* and config/initializers/myplugin.rb. See the release notes for more on this: http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/1/4/rails-3-2-0-rc2-has-been-released. (called from <top (required)> at /app/config/environment.rb:2)
2013-07-12T03:05:21.841751+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Using rack adapter
2013-07-12T03:05:21.841751+00:00 app[web.1]: Connecting to database specified by DATABASE_URL
2013-07-12T03:05:23.382849+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-12T03:05:22.241366+00:00 app[web.1]: ruby: symbol lookup error: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10/lib/rubyeventmachine.so: undefined symbol: rb_enable_interrupt
2013-07-12T03:05:22.239348+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
2013-07-12T03:05:22.239348+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Maximum connections set to 1024
2013-07-12T03:05:22.239348+00:00 app[web.1]: >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:35563, CTRL+C to stop
2013-07-12T03:05:23.374312+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-12T03:05:29.748682+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-12T03:05:30.170778+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-12T03:08:14.843800+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake copycopter:project NAME=My Project Name USERNAME=admin PASSWORD=password` by foobar@xyzzy.com
2013-07-12T03:08:20.694207+00:00 heroku[run.1389]: Awaiting client
2013-07-12T03:08:20.742807+00:00 heroku[run.1389]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake copycopter:project NAME=My Project Name USERNAME=admin PASSWORD=password`
2013-07-12T03:08:21.977568+00:00 heroku[run.1389]: State changed from starting to up
2013-07-12T03:08:27.647200+00:00 heroku[run.1389]: Process exited with status 1
2013-07-12T03:08:27.670344+00:00 heroku[run.1389]: State changed from up to complete
2013-07-12T03:08:53.981716+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake copycopter:project NAME=MyProjectName USERNAME=admin PASSWORD=password` by foobar@xyzzy.com
2013-07-12T03:09:00.543650+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: Awaiting client
2013-07-12T03:09:00.597438+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake copycopter:project NAME=MyProjectName USERNAME=admin PASSWORD=password`
2013-07-12T03:09:01.900564+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: State changed from starting to up
2013-07-12T03:09:06.612032+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: Process exited with status 0
2013-07-12T03:09:06.625397+00:00 heroku[run.5825]: State changed from up to complete
2013-07-12T03:09:11.063317+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-12T03:09:11.277609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-12T03:09:12.850149+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-12T03:09:13.020609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-12T03:09:41.765591+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-12T03:09:42.022288+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=myname.herokuapp.com fwd="XX.XXX.XXX.XX" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. I changed the gemfile of copycopter-server locally:

rails 3.2.6 to rails 3.2.13
"source :rubygems" must be "source "https://rubygems.org"
and most importantly your eventmachine version in gemfile.lock must be updated to :
"eventmachine (1.0.3)"

And then run bundle update rails, bundle install and push to heroku again, and heroku run rake db:migrate again.

Hope this works for you too!

references: https://github.com/copycopter/copycopter-server/issues/86